# htaccess to https subdomain and wordpress child theme - too many redirects?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

A bit out of my comfort zone, hoping someone can point me in the right direction!
I need to force all http://www.mywebsite.com to go to https://sub.mywebsite.com.

So, I need to force all visitors to the sub-domain, but also the secure https version.

I've tried editing the root htaccess file but I get 'too many redirects' error.
The new site is using a Wordpress child theme in case that makes a difference - when I edited the root htaccess the site appeared unstyled and the 'too many redirects' error related to CSS and JS files.

I'm sure it's something silly and small but any help, much appreciated! :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this into the htaccess file above all other existing rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# First redirect to the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Then ensure HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Totally fixed the problem - you are awesome thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help :)